# What usage do left tortoise shell brackets (〔) play in plays?

Tags: punctuation

The beginning of *Press-Ganging Able-Bodied Men*《抓壮丁》has the following passage filled with three consecutive lines starting with left tortoise shell brackets (〔) :

> [image]

and transcription:

> 〔中秋节前一天。
>   〔一个暴发户，货高利货，大斗进小斗出，盘剥起家的地主的堂屋。（如在广场演出，只要一张桌子，四根板凳或椅子就行了。）
>   〔开幕时，李老拴坐在桌前抽水烟，一边唱着《江油关》。

I find it especially interesting that the brackets don't close, i.e.: you don't see the opposite facing tortoise shell bracket (〕) close off the sentences.

What role do these "〔" brackets play here?

Comment: 六角符號 ＂〔〕＂多被稱爲＂舞臺提示符號＂。另一半＂〕＂不寫的原因嘛，可能是被英語標點用法的習慣影響的。例: https://style.mla.org/speech-paragraphs-quotation-marks/ **Use a closing quotation mark**, however, only at the end of the person’s speech, **not at the end of every paragraph**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are reading is a play script.

It is one of the common ways to mark non-dialogue lines in the script with "〔" or "[" ahead of the line. So in this case it's not actually functioning as half bracket, but rather just a head mark.